# Emacs Blue color too dark

Tags: faces, colors

Emacs blue (on dark background) is too dark. `classA` is readable with difficulty in the example below:

[image]

How to fix the dark blue colour?

Comment: Are you using the terminal and a theme that's aware of dark/light backgrounds? In this case it could be that Emacs doesn't detect your terminal's background color correctly (as it's just guessing) and customizing `frame-background-mode` will fix it and other faces.

Comment: @wasamasa's comment is applicable to my situation. It should be made into an answer IMO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add [`frame-background-mode`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-28.0.90/lisp/frame.el#L1158-L1166) to your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html):

```
(setq frame-background-mode 'dark)
```

Comment: This is the best answer, affirming the 2nd highest vote getter is the most correct in stack exchange.

Comment: I agree, I have upvoted (both this answer and @wasamasa's answer) and I've commented on the superiority of this answer to mine (the current top vote getter). The main problem is that it came about a month after mine. wasamasa's answer came only three days after and should have been *the* answer but the OP took another month to post his answer and mark it correct. It's probably that time gap that explains the situation here, not any tongue-in-cheek "2nd is first" SE phenomenon :-)

Comment: [Light](https://i.imgur.com/A8ABLRZ.png), [dark](https://i.imgur.com/2FJZ9km.png). Am I doing it wrong? Any prerequisites? That's `emacs -Q`.

Comment: @x-yuri : You should post this as a separate question. Nobody will see a comment that was posted two years after the original answer (and well, yes, I saw it, but it was purely an accident :-) )

Comment: @NickD It doesn't add much. The one who sees will see. And the the Occam's razor says me to [stop it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ow0lr63y4Mw) (c) :) It's probably best to edit this answer.

Answer (score 19):

Put the cursor on the blue word, and say `C-u C-x =`. Find the `face` entry and click on its value. Then click on `customize this face` and change the foreground value to e.g. `Cyan1`.

If you are in a console or are doing `emacs -nw` in a terminal, instead of clicking, put the cursor on the appropriate element and press `RET`.

Comment: How can I move the  cursor in `emacs -nw` mode to the right pane? <kbd> RET </kbd>  the same as <kbd> ENTER </kbd>?

Comment: `C-x o` will cycle through the windows. And yes, `RET` is the commonly used emacs name for the key that is usually labeled `Enter`.

Comment: I managed to do it.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: If the problem is to change *one* face (or a few), then my answer stands. But if the problem is as @wasamasa describes in the comment to the question and the answer below, then that is the better answer: customize `frame-background-mode`.

Comment: I'm trying to do this on a console and  `C-u C-x` makes the selected word ALL CAPS :(  Is there a meta-x command I could type in instead?

Comment: Try `C-u M-x what-cursor-position RET` but you should fix your setup: C-x is much too valuable as a prefix to waste.

Answer (score 11):

Faces in Emacs can have different values, depending on display attributes such as the number of colors supported or whether they're displayed on a light/dark background.  Emacs can guess the latter without any issues in graphical mode, for textual frames however the guessing isn't nearly as good.  If it turns out to be wrong, you'll get dark blue on black (because it mistakenly assums a light background on which there would be enough contrast to the dark blue), like in the screenshot above.

To check whether that's the case for you, inspect the value of `frame-background-mode` and customize it if needed.

Comment: That's much better than changing it a face at a time. Thanks!

Comment: How can one inspect the `frame-background-mode`?

Comment: Same like any variable, with `F1 v` followed by its name.

Answer (score 5):

NickD has a good answer but doesn't update your menu bar which may also have the same dark blue (can you see what it says when you type `ctrl + s`?).  This method will also fix hard to read menus.

1. Run emacs
2. Type `alt + x customize-themes`
3. Arrow down to **manoj-dark** and hit return (or pick a different theme)
4. Type `ctrl + x, ctrl + s` to save the settings
5. Type `ctrl + x, ctrl + c` to quit

This theme is saved to your `.emacs` file and will be used when you use emacs in the future. Here are [more exhaustive instructions](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_playing_with_color_theme.html).

Comment: `tango-dark` was perfect for me!

Answer (score 0):

To change the colors of a part of a text, you put the cursor there, press [`C-u C-x =`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Position-Info.html), and find the face name:

[image]

Knowing the face name you can change the foreground ([`M-x set-face-foreground`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html#index-set_002dface_002dforeground)), or the background ([`M-x set-face-background`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html#index-set_002dface_002dbackground)). There's also ([`set-face-attribute`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html#index-set_002dface_002dattribute)):

```
(set-face-attribute 'package-name nil :foreground "cyan1")
```

Replace `package-name` with the desired face name. `nil` means "for existing and newly created frames."

To display the list of colors use [`M-x list-colors-display`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Colors.html).

You can execute non-interactive functions (like `set-face-attribute`) via `M-:`, in a scratch buffer ([`C-x C-e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html)), or put them into `~/.emacs`.

The same applies to interactive functions (like `set-face-foreground`, `set-face-background`). But they can also be executed via `M-x`.