# Quick temporary colour change

Tags: colors, coloring

I'm using a dark theme to write Clojure, with rainbow parentheses etc.

I like this theme and its syntax colouring, and I don't want to change it or mess it up.

BUT ... I'm currently sitting outside in a place with lots of sunlight and I can't read the screen.

What I'd like to be able to do is quickly, and *temporarily* (just in this session) invert the main colours : switch to a white background and black text (the other syntax colours I'm happy to keep the same)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emacs Blue color too dark](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35959/emacs-blue-color-too-dark)

Comment: ... and look for the accepted answer, not the highest-voted one (although you should read that one too :-))

Comment: Would it work for changing the background colour?

Comment: No, `frame-background-mode` tells emacs whether your background is dark or light, so that it can adjust all the **other** colors to make them visible against the background you have.

Comment: OK - now I see I misread the question: you want to switch the background and keep everything else the same. But try it in any case, and see if it makes things readable.

Comment: Try `M-x invert-face RET default RET` possibly in combination with customizing  `frame-background-mode` to `light`. To go back , do the `invert-face` again and  change the customization of `frame-background-mode` to `dark` (or set it to nil).

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question in your title, if you don't like the colors of a particular part of the text, you put the cursor there, press [`C-u C-x =`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Position-Info.html), and find the face name:

[image]

Knowing the face name you can change the foreground ([`M-x set-face-foreground`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html#index-set_002dface_002dforeground)), the background ([`M-x set-face-background`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html#index-set_002dface_002dbackground)) or any other [attribute](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html) ([`set-face-attribute`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html#index-set_002dface_002dattribute)):

```
(set-face-attribute 'package-name nil :weight 'bold)
```

Replace `package-name` with the desired face name. `nil` means "for existing and newly created frames."

About foreground and background of the current frame, use [`M-x set-foreground-color`, and `M-x set-background-color`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418648/how-to-set-default-emacs-background-and-foreground-colors).

To display the list of colors use [`M-x list-colors-display`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Colors.html).

You can execute non-interactive functions (like `set-face-attribute`) via `M-:`, in a scratch buffer ([`C-x C-e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html)), or put them into `~/.emacs`.

The same applies to interactive functions (like `set-face-foreground`, `set-face-background`, `set-foreground-color`, `set-background-color`). But they can also be executed via `M-x`.