# Adjust unreadable blue color for rustic mode

Tags: colors, rust

When using clippy with rustic mode, I'm unable to read any of the blue messages on my screen. I would like to change the color so I can read these messages.

[image: unreadable font]

Existing answers tell me to adjust the font settings, yet I can't seem to find the font face here:

[image: font description]

How would I go about redefining "blue2" to be a more readable shade of blue?

Comment: See [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36032/14825)  for a possible solution.  If that does not work, try [my answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35961/14825) to the same question. If one of these answers your question, this question can be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looking into rustic-mode](https://github.com/brotzeit/rustic/blob/master/rustic-compile.el#L118) revealed `rustic-ansi-faces`, which can be used to customize the colors in which the cargo compilation output is displayed. I changed it to the following for better legibility:

```
(setq rustic-ansi-faces ["black"
                              "red2"
                              "green3"
                              "yellow3"
                              "cyan2"
                              "magenta3"
                              "cyan3"
                              "white"])
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the face is `xterm-color`.  I believe you are using this package [**`xterm-color.el`**: *An ANSI control sequence to text-property translator*.](https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color)

Are you running any shell commands that turns on color output?  Are you looking at the error messages of a compiler, and the compiler colorizes the output, and `Emacs` picks up those colors?  (IIRC, with `rg`, `ag` and language compilers commands turns on colour on the output)

There is dissonance between the `Emacs` themes, and the colors output by these commands.

You have the following options

- Look at the command line option of your linter, compiler, or search commands, and disable the color option.
- Or disable `xterm-colors` to see if there is a change in the situation.

Comment: Thanks, this prompted me to look into the rustic-mode package which uses xterm-color internally. There I could configure the color - see my answer.